# Pyproj returns inf when coordinates are inside bounds

Tags: python, coordinate-system, pyproj

I'm trying to parse the data from [GHSL-POP](https://ghsl.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ghs_pop2019.php), converting coordinates to real-world latitudes and longitudes. But pyproj returns inf value for some coordinates that are inside bounds. Here is my code:

```
proj = pyproj.proj.Proj('+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs')
p(-1799999.0, 8900000.0, inverse=True)
    (-110.45058006895013, 86.52427143263158)
p(-18040875.0, 8999875.0, inverse=True) #this is coordinates at pixel(0,0)
    (inf, inf)
```

Boundary is:

```
BoundingBox(left=-18041000.0, bottom=-9000000.0, right=18041000.0, top=9000000.0)
```

Comment: What happens when you set `errcheck=True`? https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/proj.html#pyproj.Proj.__call__

Comment: @snowman2 It's said `pyproj.exceptions.ProjError: transform error: Point outside of projection domain`. I thought all the coordinates in dataset should be valid, but seems not?

Comment: That does seem to be the case.

Comment: Your second point is in fact outside the projection limits. Your point falls inside the bounding box, but outside the projection extent, because Mollweide has the shape an ellipse, and the point is outside that ellipse . That's why it can't be transformed to lon/lat.

Comment: Thanks @FSimardGIS. Does the proj initialization look right to you? Actually I visualized the output lat/lng, and found it didn't match the real world shape. So there should be sth wrong with projection...

Comment: I got the exact same results as you when reprojecting your points.